# How to groupBy a list and map the result to another list

Tags: c#

I have the following piece of code:

```
 public List<myTask> MyTask { get; set; }


 public class myTask
{
    public List<int> ID { get; set; }
    public List<DateTime> Date { get; set; }
    public Decimal Total { get; set; }
 }
 List<myTask> tempTask = new List<myTask>();
 MyTask = new List<myTask>();
```

I want to do something as follows but having the error message:

```
MyTask = tempTask.GroupBy(x => x.Date);
```

> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable,MvcUI.Models.MyTask>>'
>   to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

---

Edited Code:

I have tried to add the code:

```
var newtempTask = tempTask.GroupBy(x => x.Date, (Date, values) =>


 new
                    {
                        ID = values.Select(x => x.ID).ToList(),
                        Date = values.Select(x => x.Date).ToList(), Total=values.Select(x => x.Date).ToList() 
                                                                          }); and then 
        foreach (var newitem in newtempTask)
        {
            MyTask.Add(new MyTask
                           {
                               ID = newitem.ID,
                               Date= newitem.Date,Total = newitem.Total
                           });}
```

> I have tried to add the code, please see the above edited code. I am having the error message, Error 7 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You lack explanations on what you are trying to achieve...
I think the following could be what you are asking for:
(it selects the first task in each group by date)

```
 List<myTask> tempTask = new List<myTask>();
 // fill tempTask
 List<myTask> Task = (from t in tempTask
                      group t by t.Date into g
                      select g.First()).ToList();
```

Or do you perhaps want new tasks for each date with the IDs of all tasks in that group and the sum of the totals?

In that case the query is a little more complex:

```
   List<myTask> Task2 = (from t in tempTask 
                         group t by t.Date into g
                         select
                           new myTask
                             {
                              ID = new List<int>(g.SelectMany(t => t.ID)),
                              Date = g.Key,
                              Total = g.Sum(t => t.Total)
                             }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you `GroupBy` you no longer have `List<myTask>` as type.
As you are grouping by a list (is this intended?) you will have to change the declaration of MyTask to:

```
public IEnumerable<IGrouping<List<DateTime>, myTask>> MyTask { get; set; }
```

Comment: I have tried to add the code, please see the above edited code.  I am having the error message, Error 7 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.List<int>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>'

Comment: I don`t want to group by a list

Comment: Then what do you want to group by? You have a property `List<DateTime> Date` which probably should be `DateTime Date`?

Comment: Actually I am doing a groupBy by date[0], but even with var newtempTask = tempTask.GroupBy(x => x.Date[0], (Date, values) =>... it does not work

Comment: Then show the code that does that. You have to show the exact code that you are using. For instance what is `GroupedTask`?

Comment: Actually I am doing a groupBy by date and the new error message is on the line ID = newitem.ID...Error 25 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.List<int>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>'